# App unable to find AVAudio BluetoothHFP Handsfree port Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, avaudiosession

In my app I want to check for the AVAudio portTypes already connected to the phone. The code below works for BluetoothA2DP and Headphones, but not BluetoothHFP when I connect the phone to my car handsfree. Can anyone help me?! I think have been through all the SO posts on Handsfree/AV/Bluetooth, and many others, but can't work out why it is not recognising the BluetoothHFP output portType.

```
import AVFoundation

func startCheckAVConnection() {

    // set the AVAudioSession to allow bluetooth. This do/try/catch doesn't seem to make a difference if it is here or not.
    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth)
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }

    // Check possible outputs for handsfree
    let outputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs

    if outputs.count != 0 {
        for output in outputs {
            if output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP {
                peripheralLabel.text = "connected to BluetoothA2DP"
            } else if output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP { // NOT RECOGNISED
                peripheralLabel.text = "connected to BluetoothHFP"
            } else if output.portType == AVAudioSessionPortHeadphones {
                peripheralLabel.text = "connected to Headphones"
            }
        }
    } else {
        peripheralLabel.text = "Please connect handsfree"
    }

    // Add observer for audioRouteChangeListener
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(TopVC.audioRouteChangeListener(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange,
        object: nil)
}
```

Comment: What value for `output.portType` do you get in that case? How many outputs do you have? Could it be that you have various, and `peripheralLabel.text` get overwritten with another value?

Comment: Hi Larme, there is only one .portType when it picks up A2DP or Headphones, but it never picks up BluetoothHFP. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add setActive after setCategory.

```
 do { try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("setActive")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to send sounds to the HFP port - is there any way to automatically do so if one exists or does the app have to manually set this up and reroute the sound?  I will post another question about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your category setup to:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth)
```

HFP doesn't work with multi-route category AFAICT.

Comment: hi Austino, thanks I tried PlayAndRecord and is still doesn't pick up HFP. It picks up A2DP fine, but not HFP. Any  more ideas?

Comment: I needed also to add SetActive after SetCategory. Now works fine. do { try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("setActive")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }